# creating classes in matlab or converting c code in matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

how can i create classes in matlab....please explain using example.

i want to create class operation
in that class there should be 3 functions
add,multiply,minus....
and i want to access it through .m file

i am posting rough c code and i want this to be done in matlab

```
class operation
{
    public:

    function add(int a,int b)
    {
        return(a+b);
    }

    function minus(int a,int b)
    {
        return(a-b);
    }
}

void main()
{
    int a,b;
    operaion o;
    cout<<o.add(2,4)<<endl;
    cout<<o.minus(3,5);  

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: This is not a valid C++ in the first place...

Comment: this is just a rough code

Comment: So what have you tried ?  What have you learnt from the documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this as your class in an .m file (e.g. operation.m)

```
classdef operation
    methods
        function c = add(obj, a, b)
            c = a + b;
        end
        function c = minus(obj, a, b)
            c = a - b;
        end
        function c = multiply(obj, a, b)
            c = a * b;
        end

        %.... add whatever other functions

    end
end
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
obj = operation;
obj.add(1,2)
obj.minus(1,2)
obj.multiply(1,2)
```

With that said, I'd highly recommend that you read the matlab documentation for this, as it's quite thorough. You can start here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html

Answer (score 0):

Heres one example taking the C code you attached in question.For simplicity the name of files are kept same as function name in C

Make three files as shown below :

> add.m

function [result]=add(a,b)

result=a+b;

> minus.m

function [result]=diff(a,b)

result=a-b;

> main.m

a=input('Enter one number:');

b=input('Enter Second number:');

add_res=add(a,b)

diff_res=diff(a,b)

Comment: can i do all functions in one file...because i have 20-25 functions...so calling every file will take too much of time

Comment: You can use matlab inline function. But it is recommended that inline functions should be used only when the amount of logic inside function is very less. Details about inline function can be found here :http://pundit.pratt.duke.edu/wiki/MATLAB:Inline_Function

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've written but it's not an answer to the question which asks, explicitly, for guidance on the creation of classes in Matlab.  No, I'm not going to provide that guidance either, that's what the, generally very good, documentation is for.